# Can Eclipse be configured to use "favorites" without static imports?

Tags: java, eclipse, static, static-methods, static-import

I’d like to configure Eclipse with some “favorite” static-method collections, but without using static imports.

For example, if I add `com.google.common.collect.Lists` the list in Window » Preferences » Java » Editor » Content Assist » Favorites, I can type “`newA`”, press Ctrl-Space, and pick the `Lists.newArrayList` method from that list. But:

1) If “static imports” is enabled in Preferences » Java » Editor » Content Assist, the result is that Eclipse adds a static import for `com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList` and auto-completes my code to `newArrayList(...)`.

2) If “static imports” is disabled, then:

2.a) If the class with the static method is not imported, it adds an import for the class, and auto-completes to `Lists.newArrayList(...)`, which is exactly what I want. However,

2.b) If the class with the static method is already imported, then it just auto-completes to `newArrayList(...)`, which of course doesn’t compile.

My question is: Is there a way to configure Eclipse so that (2.b) behaves like (2.a) all the time? (I.e. so that it auto-completes favorite static methods with their class name prefix even when the class is already imported.)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly to the point, but you can define a template and when you select it, you get both the import and the code. Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates`, add a new one with name `newA` and the pattern `${staticImport:importStatic('com.google.common.collect.Lists')}Lists.newArrayList(${cursor})`

In your method body, type `newA` and hit `CTRL+Space` and you should see the following:
[image]